# Why do ServiceStack.Text custom deserialization settings not apply?

Tags: c#, serialization, servicestack

I use ServiceStack.Text with ServiceStack (the web service framework).

I'm trying to add a custom serialization route for a specific type in `AppHost.Configure()`. However, the settings do not apply/are ignored.

```
public AppHost : AppHostBase 
{
    ...

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        //Register custom serialization routine
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<CultureInfo>.SerializeFn = r => r.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<CultureInfo>.DeSerializeFn = r => return new CultureInfo(r);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ServiceStack.Text is caching internally very heavily to achieve fast performance. ServiceStack  is already starting the cache creation process before `AppHost.Configure()` is called.

So to resolve this issue, you need to register your settings before `AppHost.Init()` is called.

Of course this isn't required for all settings in ServiceStack.Text - it's only required for the settings which will be cached before `AppHost.Configure()` is called.

Comment: Could you please provide the source for the info in the first paragraph? I have a similar problem with ServiceStack.Text cache and your slution is not possible in my case.

Comment: Thanks... was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it wasn't calling my custom deserializer... moved the line setting JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn into the AppHost constructor instead of .Configure() and that solved the problem.